# Keyboard navigation inside Excel modal dialogs

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

The following dialog is not accepting tab or space to arrows to navigate. How can this be done without resorting to the mouse?  Going to the mouse is slow and I sometimes then hit the wrong radio button. What a horrible UI: i hope there's some way around this.

[image]

Comment: I have no problem with navigating from keyboard: TAB moves between radio buttons block, Cancel and OK. Within radio buttons block up and down arrow work for navigation/selecting (Monterey & Office365)

Comment: @AivarPaalberg  Any ideas why the discrepancy in behavior?